# prove that $\lim _{x \to \infty} x\sin x$ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits

i don't even know how to start.. just how we can turn choosen $\epsilon$ into $M$ so that we can find suitable $x$ if L is unknown ?

Answer (score 2):

What about taking $$x_n=2n\pi\quad \text{and}\quad y_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi,$$ for all $n$, and see what $$\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n\sin(x_n)\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{n\to \infty }y_n\sin(y_n)$$
are ?

Comment: thanks,yes i know it can change $x$ into constant and zero with that values , but i supposed prove it by $\delta - \epsilon$ language , and what i know it started with choosing $\epsilon$

Comment: You have all information to do it ! (this technique is entirely equivalent to the $\varepsilon -\delta $)... But honestly, using $\varepsilon -\delta $ proof to prove non convergence is really not efficient...